# SmartyException: "Unable to load template 'file:group2summary.tpl'"

Tags: civicrm.settings.php

I have a CiviCRM plugin in my worpdress website and am getting following exception while clicking on single "View" in contacts :

```
SmartyException: "Unable to load template 'file:group2summary.tpl'"
```

I updated my CiviCRM to 5.70.1, all extensions including "group2summary" seem to be up-to-date. I cleared CiviCRM cache but it did not help. My Wordpress and all plugins are up-to-date. Any ideas on what else can be done?

Here is exception log:

```
#0 /home/globalphil/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/smarty3/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatebase.php(232): Smarty_Internal_Template->render(FALSE, 0)
#1 /home/globalphil/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/smarty3/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatebase.php(116): Smarty_Internal_TemplateBase->_execute(Object(Smarty_Internal_Template), NULL, NULL, NULL, 0)
#2 /home/globalphil/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Region.php(81): Smarty_Internal_TemplateBase->fetch("group2summary.tpl")
#3 /home/globalphil/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Region.php(157): CRM_Core_Region->{closure}((Array:8))
#4 /home/globalphil/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Smarty/plugins/block.crmRegion.php(26): CRM_Core_Region->render("          \n      \n  <div><input name=\"entryURL\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"h...", TRUE)
#5 /home/globalphil/public_html/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/templates_c/en_US/09/db/ee/09dbee8c8e3bca9eaff6bf395a1dbee9d7666bc5_0.file.CMSPrint.tpl.php(107): smarty_block_crmRegion((Array:1), "          \n      \n  <div><input name=\"entryURL\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"h...", Object(Smarty_Internal_Template), FALSE)
#6 /home/globalphil/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/smarty3/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_template_resource_base.php(123): content_65e502b040bc80_61552004(Object(Smarty_Internal_Template))
#7 /home/globalphil/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/smarty3/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_template_compiled.php(114): Smarty_Template_Resource_Base->getRenderedTemplateCode(Object(Smarty_Internal_Template))
#8 /home/globalphil/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/smarty3/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_template.php(216): Smarty_Template_Compiled->render(Object(Smarty_Internal_Template))
#9 /home/globalphil/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/smarty3/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_template.php(385): Smarty_Internal_Template->render()
#10 /home/globalphil/public_html/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/templates_c/en_US/36/00/0d/36000d975f6d067785f581437bd6e0167ea5fa53_0.file.wordpress.tpl.php(31): Smarty_Internal_Template->_subTemplateRender("file:CRM/common/CMSPrint.tpl", NULL, NULL, 0, 3600, (Array:0), 0, FALSE)
#11 /home/globalphil/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/smarty3/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_template_resource_base.php(123): content_65e502b03ecbf0_29524232(Object(Smarty_Internal_Template))
#12 /home/globalphil/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/smarty3/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_template_compiled.php(114): Smarty_Template_Resource_Base->getRenderedTemplateCode(Object(Smarty_Internal_Template))
#13 /home/globalphil/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/smarty3/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_template.php(216): Smarty_Template_Compiled->render(Object(Smarty_Internal_Template))
#14 /home/globalphil/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/smarty3/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatebase.php(232): Smarty_Internal_Template->render(FALSE, 0)
#15 /home/globalphil/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/smarty3/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatebase.php(116): Smarty_Internal_TemplateBase->_execute(Object(Smarty_Internal_Template), NULL, NULL, NULL, 0)
#16 /home/globalphil/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Page.php(273): Smarty_Internal_TemplateBase->fetch("CRM/common/wordpress.tpl")
#17 /home/globalphil/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contact/Page/View/Summary.php(122): CRM_Core_Page->run()
#18 /home/globalphil/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(322): CRM_Contact_Page_View_Summary->run((Array:3), NULL)
#19 /home/globalphil/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(69): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:18))
#20 /home/globalphil/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(36): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:3))
#21 /home/globalphil/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php(1231): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:3))
#22 /home/globalphil/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(324): CiviCRM_For_WordPress->invoke("")
#23 /home/globalphil/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(348): WP_Hook->apply_filters("", (Array:1))
#24 /home/globalphil/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(517): WP_Hook->do_action((Array:1))
#25 /home/globalphil/public_html/wp-admin/admin.php(259): do_action("toplevel_page_CiviCRM")
#26 {main}
```

And here are warnings from debug.log (I did not see them before) :

```
[03-Mar-2024 23:11:23 UTC] PHP Notice:  Indirect modification of overloaded property CRM_Core_Smarty::$template_dir has no effect in /home/globalphil/public_html/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext/org.wikimedia.geocoder/geocoder.civix.php on line 107
[03-Mar-2024 23:11:23 UTC] PHP Notice:  Indirect modification of overloaded property CRM_Core_Smarty::$template_dir has no effect in /home/globalphil/public_html/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext/coop.palantetech.exportprimaryemails/exportprimaryemails.civix.php on line 100
[03-Mar-2024 23:11:23 UTC] PHP Notice:  Indirect modification of overloaded property CRM_Core_Smarty::$template_dir has no effect in /home/globalphil/public_html/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext/eu.tttp.group2summary/group2summary.civix.php on line 100
[03-Mar-2024 23:11:23 UTC] PHP Notice:  Indirect modification of overloaded property CRM_Core_Smarty::$template_dir has no effect in /home/globalphil/public_html/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext/contactnotes/contactnotes.civix.php on line 100
```

Answer (score 1):

Its a known issue for Smarty3, I have pushed a PR for the https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/group2summary/-/merge_requests/11

You can apply the patch or comment `CIVICRM_SMARTY3_AUTOLOAD_PATH` line in your civicrm.settings.php

Comment: thanks a lot for the quick reply @Pradeep Nayak! could you please specify what exactly would need to be done with `CIVICRM_SMARTY3_AUTOLOAD_PATH` variable in civicrm.settings.php? Currently it is set to 

`define('CIVICRM_SMARTY3_AUTOLOAD_PATH', '/home/{****}/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/smarty3/vendor/autoload.php');`

Comment: remove the whole line for now until the maintainer fixes the issue

Comment: thank you, it solved the problem!

Comment: Are you okay to mark this post as answered thn to help others who will face similar problem

Comment: We are having this too, but with `SmartyException: "Unable to load template 'file:CRM/common/TrackingFields.tpl' in 'CRM/Event/Form/Registration/Confirm.tpl'"`. In our `civicrm.settings.php` there is no `CIVICRM_SMARTY3_AUTOLOAD_PATH`, only `CIVICRM_SMARTY_AUTOLOAD_PATH`(without the `3`). Commenting out those lines did not help. Are there any other workarounds? Should this fix be applied to other Smarty mixins, such as `mixin/smarty-v2@1`?

Comment: The trackingField file has been removed since 5.66. https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/27233/files

You may have custom template over-ride for CRM/Event/Form/Registration/Confirm.tpl file which you need to update to remove the reference.

Comment: This reminded me that there was a warning when adding the recommended `CIVICRM_SMARTY3_AUTOLOAD_PATH` var in civicrm.settings.php that it could cause issues. I was getting a very similar to the above after adding this variable, with a MailChimp extension I had installed. Removing this setting fixed the template loading issue for the extension